# first issue with first linq

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I'm using vs2008 framework 3.5 and i'm looking about linq for first time, following these http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb385164(v=vs.90).aspx

Creating data source like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb385204(VS.90).aspx

But i can't import/use linq.  Making a consoleApplication System.Core.dll reference and imports System.Linq should be automatic right?!

writing in main:

```
Dim students = GetStudents()
'Dim students As List(Of Student) = GetStudents() 'the same thing with this one
Dim studentQuery = From currentStudent In students _
                   Where currentStudent.Rank <= 10 _
                   Select currejt
```

The IDE doesn't like students in the query and says:

```
Error   1   Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of ConsoleApplication1.Module1.Student)' 
is not queryable. Make sure you are not missing an assembly reference and/or namespace 
import for the LINQ provider. ConsoleApplication1
```

where i'm wrong!?

If i try 'Imports System.Linq' it says

> Warning   1   Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.Linq'
>   doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the
>   namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public
>   member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

Comment: Well *do* you have a reference to System.Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference and import are different - you have to reference that dll from your project (System.Core, where the System.Linq namespace resides) in order to be able to import it to your class...

Right click Project / References, choose add reference, go to tab ".NET" and select System.Core.

Comment: thanks that's the problem... i can't add that dll because now the projects are set on framework target 2.0, where i can change it to 3.5 ? thanks again

Comment: solved! for anyonelse with same problem:
VB project 
Project Properties --> Compile --> Advanced Compile Options
thanks